# How to calculate an integral with a step function squared?

Tags: integration

how can this integral be calculated:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [e^{-2mx}\:\theta^2(x) + 2\theta(x)\theta(-x) + e^{-2mx}\:\theta^2(-x)]  dx $

where $\theta(x)$ is the unit step function with its amplitude $0$ everywhere before $x=0$ and $\theta(-x)$ is the unit step function with its amplitude $0$ everywhere after $x=0$

**Edit:**

In a physics book I am studying, $\psi(x) = e^{-m |x|}$ (there are other constants in the $\psi$ that I think are not necessary to write).  we need to find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$

In the book, what the author does is first get

$\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ =      \begin{cases}
-me^{-mx}, & \text{if }x\text{ >0 } \\
me^{mx}, & \text{if }x\text{ <0}
\end{cases}
$= -m\theta(x)e^{-mx} + m\theta(-x)e^{mx} $

then he gets $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = -m\delta(x)e^{-mx} + m^2\theta(x)e^{-mx} -m\delta(-x)e^{mx} + m^2 \theta(-x)e^{mx} = m*(-2\delta + me^{-m|x|} )$

where $\delta(x)$ is the dirac delta function ($0$ everywhere and infinite at $x=0$)

the integral we wanted is easy to get from there. 
But I wanted to try a new approach: get the second derivative in the piecewise form, then transform it to unit step functions and evaluate the integral.

I thought that if the author's method worked, then the other method must also work because it's logical. Is there something wrong with my reasoning ?

Comment: Since $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$, the squares on $\theta$ can be omitted. Then use $\theta(x)\theta(-x) = 0$ [except _possibly_ for $x = 0$, but for integration that is irrelevant] to simplify further.

Comment: can't we somehow use Laplace transform, solve it in the "S" domain, then inverse Laplace transform it?

Comment: If you can justify the Laplace transformation etc., you can do that. But that would be akin to manipulating $$12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\pi n)^2} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\pi^{2k+1}}{2^{2k+1}(2k+1)!}$$ to compute $2-1$. Just use the simplest method you can. And by the way, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2mx}\,dx$$ does not exist.

Comment: please see the edit.

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand what you intended. And I must point out that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ isn't kosher. Classically, $\psi$ isn't differentiable. It is piecewise differentiable, however, so $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ or $\int \psi \frac{d\psi}{dx}$ is no problem. But $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ has a jump discontinuity, so $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ makes no sense classically. There's no problem with that if we understand the derivatives in the distributional sense, but since then $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ has a Dirac part, it is not integrable, and the integral makes no sense.

Comment: Well, but if we're not overly pedantic, we can note that the distribution $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ has a continuous extension to a function space containing $\psi$, and if we interpret $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ as that extension applied to the function $\psi$, that is okay. Is that the intended interpretation?